# How to get value in properties file Korea (ko) using Java

Tags: java

I have a properties file (test_ko.properties), which looks like this:

```
day=\uC77C
nominal=\uAE08\uC561
month=\uC6D4
```

To get the content of the file above I use the Resource Bundle, as follows:

```
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test", new Locale("ko"));

String day = bundle.getString("day");
String nominal = bundle.getString("nominal");
String month = bundle.getString("month");

System.out.println("#Day : " + day );
System.out.println("#Nominal : " + nominal );
System.out.println("#Month : " + month );
```

When I run it I get the following result :

```
#Day : ????
#Nominal : ????????
#Month : ????
```

How can I get the result to look like it should:

```
#Day : \uC77C
#Nominal : \uAE08\uC561
#Month : \uC6D4
```

Comment: Your commandline cannot represent those Unicode characters. This need not be a sign of an error. Write them instead to a file, in say UTF-8 and you will be able to read them as UTF-8.

Comment: Or you can use Apache Commons-configurations2 for the same

Answer (score 0):

If you have the apache-commons library, use `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`.

Or

```
String uescape(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 6);
    for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (32 <= ch && ch < 128) {
            sb.append(ch);
        } else {
            sb.append(String.format("\\u%04X", (int)ch);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This of course is an ASCII representation of the full Unicode string, as read by the resource bundle class.